# JUnit 5 testing MockMvc is null

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mockmvc

I am trying to test my 3rd year project and I am constanly getting a null pointer exception for my mockMvc. Below is the full stack trace.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.util.Assert.state(boolean, java.util.function.Supplier)'
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:379)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:312)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:265)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:78)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:139)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:124)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:88)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getTestContextManager(SpringExtension.java:202)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeAll(SpringExtension.java:76)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:189)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:132)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.util.Assert.state(boolean, java.util.function.Supplier)'
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:379)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:265)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:78)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.remove(ExtensionValuesStore.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.remove(NamespaceAwareStore.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(SpringExtension.java:88)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$14(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:145)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:145)
    ... 29 more
```

Below is the code for my tests with all the imports:

```
package c03xxx.test;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

   import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
  import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
 import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

 import CO3102.hw2.domain.User;

 @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
 @AutoConfigureMockMvc
 @SpringBootTest
 class Tests {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
 @Test
   public void testSignUp() throws Exception{
    User u = new User();
    u.setDob("31/12/1999");
    u.setEmail("testEmail@le.ac.uk");
    u.setFav_team("Liverpool");
    u.setNumber_of_friends(0);
    u.setPassword("123456");
    u.setUsername("TESTUSERNAME");
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/newUser"))
    .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}
```

Note: I have tried using SpringRunner.class - but this doesn't work as well even after the relevant dependencies are added to my build.gradle. If you need to see my dependencies I can add them. Thank you so much for taking the time to read my question.

**UPDATE:** So Now I am getting an error which I have updated above. Below is my build.gradle!

```
dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security- 
  crypto', version: '5.4.2'
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") 
compile group: 'com.qasymphony.qtest', name: 'qtest-sdk-java', version: '1.4.7'    
compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.3'
providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
compile group: 'tangrammer', name: 'java-net-http-client', version: '0.1.2'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.6'
 compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
 testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    
}
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: 
  '5.1.0.RELEASE'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
  compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test-
```

autoconfigure', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'

}

Comment: The code looks fine, perhaps some mismatch in dependencies - pls show us your pom / build.gradle file

Comment: I've sorted that out now, but instead I am getting a no such method error. I will update the question and show my build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchMethodError is a sign of a conflict in dependencies.

In your case, remove:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.1.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test-autoconfigure', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'
```

both are pulled in tranistively by `spring-boot-starter-test`, which is already a part of your dependencies.